# 'CGContextClearRect: called with non-empty path' in Canvas2d in Mac

Tags: javascript, macos, html, google-chrome, canvas

I have written a simple code to draw animated Circle with a shadow here it is

```
function animate(){
  if(i<=360){
    var rad_grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(200,200,0, 200,200,100);
    rad_grad.addColorStop(0,'#fff');
    rad_grad.addColorStop(1, '#444');

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.beginPath();  
    ctx.strokeStyle = lin_grad;
    ctx.lineWidth = 30; //20
    ctx.arc(200,200,50,0,Math.PI*(i=i+2)/180);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
    ctx.shadowBlur = 5;
    ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(68,68,68,0.7)';

    ctx.closePath();

    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  else{
    window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame();
  }
}
```

Now this code works good. There is no problem in it. But when I launch Google Chrome from Command Line in **Mac** I keep on getting `CGContextClearRect: called with non-empty path` Error in Command Line while Animation is on. however if I run same code from Command Line in Ubuntu I don't get anything.

The problem is reproducible when there are Animated Shadows. If I remove Shadow Code and keep animation then it works good. Even if I remove Animation and Keep the Shadow then also it works. Problem arises only when Shadow and Animation both are there and that error is found in Mac OS only.

I googled for `CGContextClearRect: called with non-empty path` n I found that it is related to Mac Development. I have no experience with it. Can anyone tell why such behavior is there?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you put the `clearRect()` call in a path, like this...

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.closePath();
```

the problem may go away.